# Child components not rendering as expected

Tags: reactjs

So i have two child components header and occasionlist.And i want the flow to be like header should be processed first followed by my parent component and then occasionlist component should render.
Here is my entry component app.js.Pusher is configured in app.js to capture events triggered from backend(spring).

```
    var React=require('react');
var ReactDOM=require('react-dom');
var Pusher=require('pusher-js');
/*var fetch = require('node-fetch');*/
var fetch=require('isomorphic-fetch');
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
var Header=require('./components/header.js').Header;
var OccasionList=require('./components/OccasionList.js').OccasionList;

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { items: [], holidays: [] };
  },

  componentWillMount: function() {
      alert("in mount")

    this.pusher = new Pusher("ba34e3874d4b87905f36", {
      encrypted: true,
      cluster: 'ap2',
    });
    this.channel = this.pusher.subscribe("doodles");
    this.total = 0;
    alert("in pusher")
  },


  componentDidMount: function() {
      alert("in did")
   this.channel.bind('occasionsAdded', this.occasionsAdded);

   fetch('/holidays',{credentials: 'same-origin'}).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(this.getHolidaysSuccess);

  },
  occasionsAdded: function(occasion) {
       alert("event fired");
       var selectedState=[];
      this.setState({

          selectedState:occasion

      })


      },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    // Unbind from channel events
    this.channel.unbind();

    // Unsubscribe from the Pusher channel
    this.pusher.unsubscribe(this.channel);

    // Unregister by assign them to an empty function
    this.getHolidaysSuccess = function() {};

  },


  getHolidaysSuccess: function(response) {

       alert(JSON.stringify(response))

    this.setState({
        holidays: response
    });
  },


  render: function() {
      alert("in render1")

    return (
      <div>
      <Header holidays={this.state.holidays} />
      <OccasionList occasionlist={this.state.selectedState} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

In **Header** component i am populating the select box with states and on clicking that state my action binds to spring controller and it returns a list of all occasions of that state and fires an event **occasionsAdded** in **app.js** written above and updates the occasion list.Now i want this list to be rendered on my occasion child

**Header** component

```
var React=require('react');
var ReactDOM=require('react-dom');
var fetch=require('isomorphic-fetch');
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
import {Button} from 'react-toolbox/lib/button';
import {Dropdown} from 'react-toolbox/lib/dropdown';
import Input from 'react-toolbox/lib/input';
import AppBar from 'react-toolbox/lib/app_bar';
import Navigation from 'react-toolbox/lib/navigation';
import Link from 'react-toolbox/lib/Link';

var Header = React.createClass({
      getOccasion: function(evt) {
          alert(evt.target.value)
            fetch('/holidays/occasion', {
              credentials: 'same-origin',
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
               state: evt.target.value

             })
            });
          },
  render: function() {
alert("in header")

var state=this.props.holidays.state;
const AppBarTest = () => (
          <AppBar leftIcon='menu'>
            <Navigation type='horizontal'>
            <select onChange={this.getOccasion}>
              <option value="states">States</option>
              {
                  this.props.holidays.map(function(holidays,i) {
                  return <option key={i}
                    value={holidays.state}>{holidays.state}</option>;
                })
              }
            </select>
            </Navigation>
          </AppBar>
        );

    return (
      <div>
      <AppBarTest />
     /* <select onChange={this.getOccasion}>
      <option value="states">States</option>
      {
          this.props.holidays.map(function(holidays,i) {
          return <option key={i}
            value={holidays.state}>{holidays.state}</option>;
        })
      }
    </select>*/





      </div>
    );
  }
});
module.exports.Header = Header;
```

**OccasionList** component

```
    var React=require('react');
var ReactDOM=require('react-dom');
var Pusher=require('pusher-js');
/* var fetch = require('node-fetch'); */
var fetch=require('isomorphic-fetch');
require('es6-promise').polyfill();

var OccasionList=React.createClass({


      render: function() {
          alert("in OccasionList")

        return (
          <div>
          this.props.OccasionList.map(function(occasionslist,i)
                  {
              <h1>{occasionslist.images}</h1>
                  })

          </div>
        );
      }

});

module.exports.OccasionList = OccasionList;
```

As of now after control goes to header and without doing much computations it goes to occasionlist due to which select box in header is not getting loaded and i am not able to select any state.So all i want is

1. Control should first enter app.js and then it should call first child element header.
2. It should process the header element and comes back to app.js,load the new list in state(fetching from spring controller) that has to be passed to Occasionlist element and process this child.
   Please guide

Comment: Is `getHolidaysSuccess` in app.js getting fired?

Comment: no if fetch is successful then i am calling this method to set state that it

Comment: As far as I can understand from your code, your flow is like this. Your app mounts which triggers a call to a rest api that fetches a list of holidays. This populates a select box (since the props to header change). When the select box value changes you make another call to update the occasionlist in `getOccasion`. What could be missing is the code that updates the state as a result of the `getOccasion` call. I don't understand the role of Pusher in this flow. So I would expect your app `componentDidMount` to be executed and the fetch to succeed for the nav. dropdown to be populated.

Comment: you got it right.pusher is used to bind the actions of front end with back end.and my concern is before displaying select box in header the control goes to occasionlist.

Comment: I'm guessing by "control goes to occasionlist" you mean it's render method get invoked. If so, then that's expected. You have two independent components that both get rendered by your app. What exactly is the problem with  that? You can check to see if `this.props.OccasionList` is initialized before your render occasionlist or initialize it to some reasonable value in your app. Once it's value changes  the component will be rendered again with the correct value.

Comment: var OccasionList=React.createClass({
 

 

   render: function() {
    alert("in OccasionList")
    const isTrue=this.props.occasionlist;
    if(isTrue)
     {
     
     alert("true")
     }
    else
     {
     alert("false")
     }                                                                                                                   Now as obvious props will come null for the first time.it is showing false but after that the control breaks and it does not gets back to app.js but if i delete the conditional thing then it does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145816/discussion-between-mustafa-and-vikram-saini).